# How to make queries for two different table placed in 2 different server

Tags: sql, database, oracle

I just have two servers [sm33ooo.net] and [sm22ooo.net] , i would like to make query between two different tables (tbl_doc) in server [sm33ooo.net] and (tbl_archive) in [sm22ooo.net] using oracle sql developer ,any idea ?

Answer (score 1):

you should be able to create a DBLINK on one of the databases which will allow you to query a table on that database from the other database.  I'm not sure of your setup from your post so you might need to look into the difference between private and public dblinks to decide what is relevant to you.

For example if you add your link to server sm33ooo.net called dblink then on server sm22ooo.net you will be able to write select * from tbl_doc@dblink;

Comment: REALLY IT IS WORK AND PERFECT , THANK YOU SO MUCH

Comment: glad it helped you out.